# Problem when defining a function as a finite sum

Tags: warning-messages, summation, version-8

I am using Mathematica 8.0.1.0. I defined the following function for use in [an answer on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2673636):

`f[j_] := Sum[1/(j-2k+1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}]`

I then used this function in

`NSum[(-1)^i f[i], {i, 0, 7}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

I was expecting a positive answer, but got `-0.83296130952380952381`, whereas

`N[f[0]-f[1]+f[2]-f[3]+f[4]-f[5]+f[6]-f[7], 20]`

gives `0.83296130952380952381` which is the answer I expected.

If I define the function as

`f[j_] := Evaluate[Sum[1/(j-2k+1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}]]`

then `f[0]` yields `1/8 (4 ArcTanh[1/2] - 4 (2 + ArcTanh[1/2]))` which simplifies to `-1`. This is very surprising since `f[0]` is a sum of positive values. In fact, `Simplify[f[k]]` gives the negative of what the answer should be, at least for the integers `k` that I have tried. This possibly narrows down where the problem lies when I use the original function in `NSum`

Is this a problem with version 8.0.1.0, or is this reproducible in more recent versions of Mathematica?

---

There is a second problem when I use the original function in

`NSum[(-1)^k f[k], {k, 0, 7}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

I get the errors

`Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>`

and

`NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) (-1)^k f[k] is not numerical at point k = 0. >>`

I don't understand these errors. I thought the local variable names were treated as if used in `Block`, so I don't see why the `k` in the definition of the function should interfere.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `Sum` (for `f[j]`).  I get the negative sum in V11.2.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks for the verification! I was getting a similar negative result for another sum yesterday, so I was worried my computer was possessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the symbolic sum is computed wrong:

```
Clear[f];
f[j_] := Sum[1/(j - 2 k + 1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}];

f[j] /. j -> 0.  (* sum first with symbolic limit, then with 0. substituted *)
f[0.]            (* sum with numeric limit *)
(*
  -1.
   1.  
*)
```

*Fixes:*

Restrict `j` to numeric values:

```
Clear[ff];
ff[j_Integer] := Sum[1/(j - 2 k + 1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}];
NSum[(-1)^i ff[i], {i, 0, 7}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  0.83296130952380952381  *)
```

The same thing, with `k` protected by `Module[{k},...]`:

```
Clear[ff];
ff[j_Integer] := Module[{k}, Sum[1/(j - 2 k + 1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}]];
NSum[(-1)^k fff[k], {k, 0, 7}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  0.83296130952380952381  *)
```

Avoid `Sum` (which I usually do when I want to calculate the sum of a finite number of terms):

```
Clear[fff];
fff[j_Integer] := Total@Table[1/(j - 2 k + 1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}]
NSum[(-1)^i fff[i], {i, 0, 7}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  0.83296130952380952381  *)
```

Comment: Thanks! This confirms my suspicions that there was something wrong in the symbolic sum since the symbolic result for `f[0]` simplified pretty easily to `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can read in the documentation that "NSum **first localizes the values of all variables**, then evaluates f with the variables **being symbolic**, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically".

I suggest you use `Trace` to see how different is `NSum[]` related to `N[Sum[]]`. I would simply do:

```
f[j_] := Sum[1/(j - 2 k + 1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}];
N[Sum[(-1)^(i) f[i], {i, 0, 7}], 20]

(* 0.83296130952380952380952380952380952381 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! This tells why the `k` might interfere. I will use `Trace` to investigate further. However, that `f[j_] := Sum[1/(j - 2 k + 1)/4^k, {k, 0, Floor[j/2]}];
NSum[(-1)^(i) f[i], {i, 0, 7}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` returns the negative of the correct answer still does not make sense.

Comment: I think it can help if you define `f[j_]=Sum[...]` and run `f[0]`, you might understand what is happening.

Comment: Yes, that's the same result for `f[0]` that I mention in my question: `1/8 (4 ArcTanh[1/2] - 4 (2 + ArcTanh[1/2]))` which simplifies easily to `-1`.